# Doing supervised classification for images on ERDAS?

Tags: convert, classification, erdas-imagine

i want to do a supervised classification for images on ERDAS, using GIS, i clipped the areas i want to use as training/signature from the original images. but i just can't create a signature file, because they need to be in AOI format.

I already tried to convert them to shapefiles (raster to polygon tool), and enter the shapefile on ERDAS. All tutorials i have seen so far require to cut or draw an AOI from the image manually.

How do I convert these clipped areas to AOI files without having to cut anything from them?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have this training areas in shapefile you can convert them to AOI's:

1. Open the shapefile that you want to use as training area
2. Create a new AOI file
3. Use the "Select by box" tool and draw a box around the polygons you want to select (I guess you have separated shapefiles for each class so in that case select all of the polygons)
4. The selected polygons will turn yellow
5. In the Content window select the AOI Layer and use the "paste from select object" tool to paste the polygons selected in the AOI file
6. Finally save the AOI layer and repeat with all the training areas

When you have all your training areas in AOI format proceed to do the classification

[image]